# graphql cache DataIdFromObject not causing React re-render

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have two mutations `onLike` and `onSubmit` defined in one react component. For `onLike` mutation, I can use cache with `DataIdFromObject` to update the data without refetching the data with either `this.props.data.refetch()` or `refetchQueries: []`. BUT not for `onSubmit` mutation.

// --- React component

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props
        .addLyricQuery({
            variables: {
                content: this.state.content,
                songId: this.props.params.id,
            },
        });
}

onLike(id, likes) {
    this.props.likeLyricQuery({
        variables: { id },
        optimisticResponse: {
            __typename: "Mutation",
            likeLyric: {
                id,
                __typename: "LyricType",
                likes: likes + 1,
            },
        },
    });
}

<button onClick={() => this.onLike(lyric.id, lyric.likes)}>

<button onClick={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>Submit</button>
```

// --- apollo connect

```
const enhancer = compose(
    graphql(fetchSongQuery, {
        options: props => ({
            variables: {
                id: props.params.id,
            },
        }),
    }),
    graphql(addLyricQuery, { name: "addLyricQuery" }),
    graphql(likeLyricQuery, { name: "likeLyricQuery" })
);
export default enhancer(SongDetail);
```

// --- addLyric Query

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export default gql`
    mutation AddLyricToSong($content: String, $songId: ID) {
        addLyricToSong(content: $content, songId: $songId) {
            id
            title
            lyrics {
                id
                content
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

// --- like query

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export default gql`
    mutation LikeLyric($id: ID!) {
        likeLyric(id: $id) {
            id
            likes
            content
        }
    }
`;
```

// --- apollo store

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    dataIdFromObject: o => o.id
});
```

**What do I expect to see?**

I expect the behavior between `onSubmit` and `onLike` to be the same. So when I click on either button, it should only query once, without needing to refetch the data.

**What do I see?**

`onLike` works as expected. When clicked, it only issues one mutation, and the react component is rendered immediately.

`onSubmit` leads me to a blank page, then once I refresh the page, the new data displays. I can make it work by using `refetch` or `refetchQueries: []` but that is besides the point.

Comment: How are you attaching your onSubmit and onLike handers?

Comment: arrow functions. The function does get called. I dont think that would be the problem.

Comment: @AndrewIngram updated!

Answer (score -1):

The context of the onSubmit function is not bound, and so you are not preventing default form behaviour

change:

```
<button onClick={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>Submit</button>
```

to:

```
<button onClick={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
```

Comment: arrow functions binds to the scope. es6

Comment: and please read the question, it says it is working for one button. The problem is related to graphql's `refetch`